# encoding not latin characters google map marker information

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, character-encoding

I'm using Google map API to add markers and add information to them but the problem is with the Arabic characters it's displayed like strange symbols though page encoding is utf-8

[image]

```
var locations = [
  ['<div class="content" style="dir:rtl; text-align:right;">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><?= "المنزل الأول" ?></h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<p>العنوان بالتفصيل, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
  '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['<div class="content" style="dir:rtl; text-align:right;">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">المنزل الثاني</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
  '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5]
];
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [How do I convert special UTF-8 chars to their iso-8859-1 equivalent using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396560/how-do-i-convert-special-utf-8-chars-to-their-iso-8859-1-equivalent-using-javasc)

Comment: encode either the document(when it's a inline-script) or the script(when it's external) in UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with notepad++ encoding changed from ANSI to UTF-8 and every thing worked fine