# How to change encoding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to change encoding of text given in `textbox` and display the encoded text in a new 'textbox'.
How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: What kind of encoding? There's all kinds of ways of encoding text out there.

Comment: @MikeC I want to take text like that "ùìåí" and make it into that "שלום" I know that I should encode it or fix the encoding method or something that why I came here

Comment: @MikeC After a little checking I assume it is UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert special UTF-8 chars to their iso-8859-1 equivalent using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396560/how-do-i-convert-special-utf-8-chars-to-their-iso-8859-1-equivalent-using-javasc)