# arabic string in JSONObject is not readable

Tags: java, json

i have a nested jsonobject in a jsonobject

this nested jsonobject is `{"key":"value"}` format.

Ex: this `"key"` is `"attribute_pa_%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d8%b3"`

the basic jsonobject is

```
 {
    "name": 
     {
            "attribute_pa_%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d8%b3":"4-5"
     }, 
     "stock":0
}
```

I get it in my javascript:

```
JSONObject attribute = object.getJSONObject("name");
Iterator iterator = attribute.keys();
String key = (String)iterator.next();
String issue = attribute.getString(key);
```

Those encoded chars are Arabic characters.

My question is; How can I decode those characters; So instad of having `"attribute_pa_%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d8%b3"` I would have `"attribute_pa_القياس"`.

Comment: the tag should be `Java` not `Javascript`.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396560/how-do-i-convert-special-utf-8-chars-to-their-iso-8859-1-equivalent-using-javasc

Comment: As they said this solution is the best for me                                          Srtring result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(key, "UTF-8");