# Javascript: How to encode from utf-8 to iso-8859-1 and also decode from it

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a text in UTF8, and I want to convert it to iso-8859-1.
Also I have a text in iso-8859-1 and I want to encode to UTF8.

I think it is not possible using native functions, so is there any good library to do this? I am using pure javascript for browser, not nodejs, no using webpack, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: This could be asked at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but make sure you've read their [help section](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/asking) before asking.

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `decodeURIComponent` in addition to `escape` to go to/from UTF8/ ISO-8859-1

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396560/how-do-i-convert-special-utf-8-chars-to-their-iso-8859-1-equivalent-using-javasc) for more info on it.

Decode UTF-: `fixedstring = decodeURIComponent(escape(utfstring));`

Decode ISO-8859-1: `utfstring = unescape(encodeURIComponent(originalstring));`

To see if a string is UTF-8:

```
var fixedstring;

try{
    // If the string is UTF-8, this will work and not throw an error.
    fixedstring=decodeURIComponent(escape(badstring));
}catch(e){
    // If it isn't, an error will be thrown, and we can assume that we have an ISO string.
    fixedstring=badstring;
}
```

Comment: This only works for strings that are exactly equal in UTF8 than ISO-8859-1. That's can't be called decoding.

Just tested with one simple accent like "á"  and throwed "malformed URI". This is 100% useless.

Comment: @BlackCid: You sure? `unescape(encodeURIComponent('á')) === String.fromCharCode(...new TextEncoder().encode('á'))`