# Convert text string to unicode characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode

Lets say I have a text string such as 'hey' and I have a unicode alphabet like Latin Extended-A from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). How can I map capital A to its similar A in the unicode one. I think I would need to split the english string and have it in the array but then how would it know which letter that is? Is there a library for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to this question is here:
[How do I convert special UTF-8 chars to their iso-8859-1 equivalent using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396560/how-do-i-convert-special-utf-8-chars-to-their-iso-8859-1-equivalent-using-javasc)

so essentially:

> decodeURIComponent(escape(utfstring))

Comment: I am trying to go for an effect like this website: https://metatags.io/font-generator . Where when you type in an english word and I have a whole bunch of unicode alphabets I convert with

Comment: Ah, my bad. Yes, you'll likely need a tool for mapping each letter to its corresponding special character.